# How much gas does it cost to create and/or execute a smart contract?

Tags: gas, gas-price

Curious for any other good resources for this Q!

Answer (score 1):

The cost of creation will depends on how many lines, functions and other variables you have in your contract. 
For the gas cost for executing a contract is 21000 gas plus you need to calculate all the operations you are calling. This is a gas cost table to give you an idea. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the contract. Deploying the contract cost `gas` whicih is a measure of the computational cost, and there is a price per gas called (as you will expect) gas price. The current gas price is about 6 Gwei (0.000000000006 ether).

[This tutorial](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/) helped me a lot some time ago.

hope this helps